# Create space for Android Admob banner to fill once connected and showing

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I am using an Admob banner at the top of my Android activity, I am using it in a table row, but when the screen first loads it takes a while to obviously connect and then show, once it does it pushes the screen down to take its place. Is there anyway I can ensure the space is always there so that it looks blank for a second then fills, as opposed to it always pushing everything down?

I looked up the documentation and I tried using a smart banner and also setting the table row height to a specific size but it keeps doing this.

Here is my Admob layout code:

```
      <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >



         <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a151868c65661b8"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</TableRow>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the minHeight of the AdView.

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
..
            />
```

NB I would have the AdView outside (and above) the Table. It's pretty unlikely it matches the other types in the table.